# Changing image according to theme

Tags: c#, asp.net

On page load i am adding this code

```
if (Request.Cookies["switchstyle"] != null)
{
    string  i = Request.Cookies["switchstyle"].Value;
    if(i == "1")
        ThemeImageUrl = "~/ImagesW";
    else
        ThemeImageUrl = "~/Images";
}
```

on btnpriv on i am writing the code

```
CipCalendar.TodaysDate = CipCalendar.TodaysDate.AddMonths(-1);

StoreMonthValue(CipCalendar.TodaysDate.ToString()); // storing month in a cookie.
//Month.Text = CipCalendar.TodaysDate.ToString(MONTH_FORMAT);
imgMonth.ImageUrl = ThemeImageUrl + "/CalendarImages/" + CipCalendar.TodaysDate.ToString(MONTH_FORMAT) + ".gif";
SetMonthNavigateButtonVisible();
SetYearNavigateButtonVisible();
isNextMonth = false;
SetCases();
```

its working fine, date is changing on image, but when i am using browser back btn this code is not working..

based on theme change when i press btnpriv as well as browser back btn date should change which is not happening now on click of browser back btn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 think that you can do.

First when you change the theme, then use a redirect() to reload the page and user can not go back. When use go back is logical to reload the page from the cache so you see the previous image.

Second disable the cache for your dynamic pages.

```
public static void DisablePageCaching() 
{ 
//Used for disabling page caching 
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false); 
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore(); 

}
```

Comment: I am using two theme black and white, on back theme jan, feb, march black image is there and on white jan feb march white image is there, by using my code is changing but when i am using the browser back btn after some time on black theme jan, feb, march white image is coming which must not show on black theme only black image show on black theme. and its not happening with white theme.

Comment: where shall i call DisablePageCaching() i am calling it on page load.

Comment: any one please help me regarding this prob.

Comment: @Abuhurera yes on page load is a good point to load it. Second try is to use Response.Redirect after your user make the them change. Redirect him to the same page - try it.

Comment: i am not getting the exact solution. i can't use response.redirect because i am changing the theme on radio btn check with the help of cookies